# WebView2 UWP Visual Studio Back Button not working

Tags: visual-studio

I am following this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2

which works well
My only problem is that there is no "back" button

I found the back button code on this page >
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/apps/design/basics/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation

I have added the code

`<Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="BackButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" IsEnabled="{x:Bind Frame.CanGoBack, Mode=OneWay}"  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Back"/>`

to   as suggested

and integrated the code "behind" to my "// App.xaml.cs"  (I can share also this code If you want)

I don't have any errors or warning, I can debug
But clicking the back button does nothing....

Can someone confirm me that this is supposed to be working ?

Thank you for your help

back button not triggering